# xrandr (1.5.0) artifacting in i3wm (4.16.1) after upgrading Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, display, xrandr, i3

Bit of an unusual issue. I just updated Arch Linux, but I hadn't rebooted in a quite awhile so it might not have even been a recent updgrade.

I'm getting some weird artifacting at the bottom of my screen now. Without a wallpaper it's just a white rectangle:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I4qR.png

When I have a wallpaper set with feh, there's a tonne of artifacting. It's like my smaller screen is superimposed on my larger screen (the wallpaper isn't suppose to cut-off half-way):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi2Ij.jpg

This artifacting only appears on my "desktop", any applications that are above it do not get the square or artifacting. But when I close the application it is still there on the desktop.

This was working fine prior to me updating, and rebooting.

When I remove my xrandr command from i3's config file, I no longer get this issue (but my screens are in the wrong order).

Here is my xrandr command:

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1280x0 --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 0x56
```

If it helps here's some information about my GPU (amdgpu):

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:62 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe83ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Any ideas? I've messed about with my xrandr command for a couple of hours since it seems to be the root of the problem, but I've had no luck. Not sure how an update could have caused this.

Comment: `amdgpu` drivers seems to be creating artifacts on different situations. Unfortunatelly, with no solutions - https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105910 - https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/3537